# why can't quotative "be like" be fronted?

Tags: syntax, english, american-english

Consider the following data (spoken American English):

- John said "I'll come."
- John was like "I'll come."
- What John said was: "I'll come."
- ?What John was like was: "I'll come."

Does anyone have an analysis of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*BE like* is not an integrated collocation meaning *SAY*. Rather, *like* is a “discourse marker” which signals that what follows is worthy of particular emphasis or peculiar interpretation.

> John was [like [totally excited about it]].
>   John was [like [jumping up and down]].
>   John was [like [“I’ll come”]].

In the ‘quotative’ version, *like* indicates that what follows is an imitation and demonstration of what John ‘was’.

So the *Wh-*cleft should be:

> **A:** John was like “Oh all right, I’ll come”—
>   **B:** No, no, no, what John was was like “I’ll come! I’ll be there!”.

Comment: You might be right, but this is already being reanalyzed by younger speakers, it seems :) http://agoraphilia.blogspot.jp/2004/04/ooh-baby-you-know-what-im-like.html

Comment: @dainichi The author reports an innovative use by his five-year-old son; we're gonna hafta wait a generation to see if this takes hold or goes the way of ordinary learning-phase overgeneralizations.